# C++ Strings and delimiters

Tags: c++, string, delimiter

So i'm doing a program where i input some data into a file and read from it. The problem is i dont know how to handle this. I read from the file and recieve a string containing alot of different data that is seperated by a delimiter "|".

```
   string data ="FirstName|LastName|Signature|Height";
```

So my question is, is there a way to seperate this string nicely and store each of the values in a seperate variable?

p.s I have tried this so far. I did find this function subrt() and find() which i could use in order to find the delimiter and take out a value but it doesnt give the correct value for me so i think i'm doing something wrong with it. Only the fname value is correct.

```
    const string DELIM = "|";
    string fname = data.substr(0, data.find(DELIM));
    string lname = data.substr(1, data.find(DELIM));
    string signature = data.substr(2, data.find(DELIM));
    string height = data.substr(3, data.find(DELIM));
```

Comment: C++ before C++11 or C++11 and after? Is that a fixed string just for testing and will be read from a file in the full program?

Comment: "C++ before C++11 or C++11 and after"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not understand how substr() works. The first parameter is not the number of character found, it is the index at which to start. See the [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). You should do the same for the find function. Something like that:

```
string const DELIM = "|";
auto const firstDelim = data.find(DELIM);
auto const secondDelim = data.find(DELIM, firstDelim + 1); // begin after the first delim
// and so on

auto fname = data.substr(0, firstDelim);
auto lname = data.substr(firstDelim + 1, secondDelim);
// and so on
```